MailMergeDataSource Find Record function leads to Execute Merge Failure
I am trying to use Visual Basic in Word to automate a MailMergeDataSource document search followed by an executed MailMerge. I have both steps working independently. However, if I call the SearchForDocument() function first, the ExecuteMerge() fails. I receive a Run-time error '5631': Word could not merge the main document with the data source because the data records were empty or no data records matched your query options.
I can run the SearchForDocument() function and note the record number. Then if I close Word and reopen without saving, I can call the ExecuteMerge() on that record number with success.
I have tried resetting the .ActiveRecord to 1 with no luck.
This VB function searches a data source for a matching doc_id, and returns the record number from the dataset. It works with no apparent issues. Returns an accurate record number from the dataset.
Function SearchForDocument(doc_id As String)
    ' Searches datasource for given record id number.
    
    Dim dsMain As MailMergeDataSource
    Dim numRecord As Integer
     
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False
    Set dsMain = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource
    'Initializes at first record because .ActiveRecord method only searches for first match in descending records from current record
    dsMain.ActiveRecord = 1
 
    If dsMain.FindRecord(FindText:=doc_id, Field:="SAMPLE") = True Then
        numRecord = dsMain.ActiveRecord
    Else
        MsgBox "Record " & doc_id & " was not found."
        numRecord = 0
    End If
    
    SearchForDocument = numRecord
  
End Function

This function executes a MailMerge from a given record number from a dataset. It works fine unless I run the SearchForDocument function first. When it fails I get run-time error '5631'.
Function ExecuteMerge(ByVal TargetRecord As Integer)    
    Set myMerge = ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    If myMerge.State = wdMainAndSourceAndHeader Or _
     myMerge.State = wdMainAndDataSource Then
     With myMerge.DataSource
     .FirstRecord = TargetRecord
     .LastRecord = TargetRecord
     End With
    End If
    With myMerge
     .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
     .Execute
     
    End With
   
End Function


I have not been able to find a way to make the VBA word .FindRecord() method work with the inbuilt .Execute() method. Replacing .FindRecord() with a loop that iterates over the data source was slow over large data sets. I have not yet gotten an ADO db connection to work, but I intend to continue to explore that option as time allows. Instead of replacing the .FindRecord() method, the following code replaces the mail merge process with an equivalent outcome that does not cause errors. This allows the code to execute VERY FAST.
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
 If .DataSource.FindRecord(FindText:="look for this", _
    Field:="look_in_here") = True Then
 End If
End With

'Now replicate the Mail Merge .execute() on the active record.

ActiveDocument.MailMerge.ShowWizard InitialState:=5, ShowPreviewStep:=True

Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy
Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
Selection.PasteAndFormat(wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

Note: this code is the simplest case of combining .FindRecord() with a merge. This method only searches records below whatever record is active in the dataset. By default it always skips checking the first record. If you intend to perform multiple searches / merges, make sure to also reset:
 .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstDataSourceRecord


"Word Could Not Merge the Main Document with the Data Source" seems to be a common error without any clear way to fix it.
This function that doesn't use .FindRecord and does not cause ExecuteMerge to fail.  I think this is our best alternative, for now.
Function SearchForDocument(doc_id As String, Optional FieldName As String = "Name") As Long
    Dim ds As MailMergeDataSource
    Set ds = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource
    
    Dim n As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = 1 To ds.RecordCount
        ds.ActiveRecord = n
        If ds.DataFields(FieldName).Value = doc_id Then
            SearchForDocument = n
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Record " & doc_id & " was not found."
End Function

Revised Code Using ADO
This function uses the ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource ConnectString and QueryString to setup an ADO connection.  This always us to use recodset.Find as a replacement to the very buggy ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FindRecord.
Function GetRowNumber(Value As Variant, FieldName As String) As Variant
    Dim Conn As Object, rs As Object
    Dim DataSource As MailMergeDataSource
    Dim ConnStr As String

    Set DataSource = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource
    ConnStr = DataSource.ConnectString
    Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open ConnStr

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.CursorLocation = 3
    rs.Open DataSource.QueryString, Conn, 1, 1 'KeySet cursor, Read-Only
    
    rs.MoveFirst
    rs.Find "[" & FieldName & "] = '" & Value & "'"
    If Not rs.EOF Then GetRowNumber = rs.AbsolutePosition
 
    rs.Close:   Set rs = Nothing
    Conn.Close: Set Conn = Nothing
End Function


I updated this value, but the error message persists.

Tried a few things including resetting to wdFirstDataSourceRecord before calling the ExecuteMerge, but my issue persists. From scratch the ExecuteMerge function works, but if I have run the .FindRecord method on the data source first it throws Run-time error '5631'.

@Jimbo I updated my answer.  Ms Word VBA is a mess.

Works, but the iteration loop is slow over large datasets. The method returns a match much quicker. It is tempting to keep trying to debug it. I've even closed the datasource and reopened it, hoping to execute the merge after this, but the error persists.

I updated my answer to use ADO.RecordSet.Find.

Getting a Run-time error on this line saying "no value given for one or more required parameters":
rs.Open SQL, Conn, 1, 1 'KeySet cursor, Read-Only
The Reference has many of these parameters as optional, so I'm not sure how to address.

I simplified the SQL.  What are you connecting to?  Is it password protected?

What is the DataSource.ConnectString and DataSource.QueryString?  You can email me at tinmanse@aol.com.

Thanks for the offer. I'm working through the code debug as I have time. First time encountering ADO & I want to learn how to use it. In the original ado code you posted, I seem to encounter a problem with Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset"). When I MsgBox rs I get a run-time error 13 Type mismatch. rs.State returns 0. FWIW the sql declaration seemed fine.

Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") creates an object pointing to my sample .xlsx data with a state = 1. This indicates that ADODB is available and working correctly.

ConnStr & Conn objects differ slightly. Conn loses a Properties key and gains a blank Database Password = "" key/value

Is the file protected?  If not then the blank password isn't an issue.  I test my code with an unprotected xlsx file.  You could always create your own connection string and query without using the DataSource.

Which reference library / libraries need to be included?
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects v? Library, and also Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset v? Library... Thanks for your help.

No password protection on the xlsx file. Included the reference libraries with the most recent version, but still get that same error on the rs.Open line. I'll try your revised code next & check the .Open documentation

Not sure whether this question is still open, but one problem you may have is that DataSource.Connectstring may be truncated, e.g. to 255 characters. If so, Conn.Open may fail because of a syntax error. Can't check right now, maybe tomorrow. Also, is the field name  in both this code and your original code exactly the same - at least some if not all Word Mailmerge functions are case-sensitive. Can't remember for ADO.

@jonsson, thank your for your comment.  I ran into that problem trying to create a new MaiMerge but had no problem creating the ADO connection (Len(ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ConnectString) is 704).

I think my problem with ADO is that my work environment is missing one of the reference libraries. I'll try again soon, but also wanted to point out this reference for further attempts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-word-create-mail-merge

Also, thank you for your comments. I think seeing the various attempts will be useful for future users.
